# gulp move files to parent directory

Tags: gulp

I'm looking for a way to copy files into their parent directory.

The problem I keep running into is that it copies the directory folders along with the files.

```
gulp.task('views:move', function() {
log('Files Moved...');
return gulp.src(paths.app + 'views/**/views/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app + '../'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) for this:

```
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src(paths.app + 'views/**/views/**/*.html')
  .pipe(rename({dirname: ''}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app + '../'));
```